# Inserting binary data with sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pickle

I would like to insert binary data in a database with `sqlite3`.

```
compressed = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(foo))
database.insert(cursor, "bar", config=compressed)
```

Here, `database` is from another module from another class, that performs `execute`. In that class, the command looks like this:

```
cursor.execute('''insert into {} {} values {}'''.format(table,columns,entries))
```

However, I am running into two different issues, both with inserting the binary data:

First, the error would say

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near '''long binary data here''' syntax error
```

Is it the case that I cannot directly store long binary data into tables in `sqlite3`?

Second, I have tried using `sqlite3.Binary()`, but that gives me something like `<memory at 0x7fd60e327108>` when I try to print out the binary data in the separate class. Attempting to do `buffer()` did not help either.

With these two issues in mind, how would I store binary data into an `sqlite3` table? I use `**kwargs` in my function; this is actually not the only argument I am using in my functions.

In addition, other parameters that did not involve binary data (simple strings and float values) did not raise an error.

Update: It occurs to me that the pickled data has some special characters in it, but I am not sure how to store those.